# Show that a certain set of stochastic processes is not closed or closed

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, self-learning

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the set of real-valued and strictly stationary processes with expectation zero and finite variance, i.e.:
\begin{equation}
    \mathcal{P}:=\left\{ X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} \, :   \, X \hbox{ is strictly stationary, } \mathbb{E} X_t = 0 \hbox{ and } \mathbb{E}[X_t^2]< \infty, \, \forall\, t \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}
\end{equation}
*Remark:* for any stochastic process $X$, we consider $Q$ the Law of a stochastic process according [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_(stochastic_processes)). We denote $X \sim Q$.

I'm trying to show whether or not $\mathcal{P}$ is closed according to the Mallows metric:

Let $X = (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} \sim P$ and $Y = (Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}\sim Q$ be two stochastic processes. In order to define the Mallows metric, for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$, let $\mathcal{M}_m$ be the random vectors $(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})$ having marginals $P\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}$ and $Q\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}$, where $\pi_{1,...,m}(  (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}} )= (X_{1},..., X_{m})$ . So:
$$d( (X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}},(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}})= \sum_{m=1}^\infty d^{(m)}(P\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}, Q\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1})2^{-m}$$
where
$$d^{(m)}(P\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}, Q\circ\pi_{1,...,m}^{-1}) = \inf_{(\tilde{X},\tilde{Y})\in \mathcal{M}_m}{(E||\tilde{X}-\tilde{Y}||^2)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}}.$$

**Update**

1.- If we take away the strict stationarity condition of the elements of $\mathcal{P}$, would it be easier to show that it is closed?

2.- Regarding the previous item, I think that strict stationarity is necessary for the metric to be well defined.